# Category to page and blocking category URL via robots.txt - good for SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I am using a template which in the pages it allows me to add sidebars / more content under and above the content I want to pull from a category which is very helpful.

If I create pages to display my categories content wont the page URLs go in conflict with the category URLs? By conflict I mean causing a duplicate content error?

What I thought might help was to block from *robots.txt* the category URLs of the blog ex. `/category/books` `/category/music`

Would that be a good practice in order to avoid the duplicate content penalty?

Comment: check this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54176/do-we-need-to-block-repeated-pages-content-for-seo-relevance/54178#54178

Comment: Should I add the canonical url from the category or from the page containing the category content? Wouldnt it be better to block it from robots.txt?

Comment: if the content on the page are same you can use canonical by blocking from robots.txt is not practical sometimes (deal with hundreds of urls). or you can use noindex,nofollow for those links

Comment: Thanks, I went and learned how to use canonical urls in wordpress and now the problem is solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best usage is using canonical URLs from the page you won't to not be so "pretty" to the "pretty" ones I found this to be in other words something like a small 301 redirect.

Here is a video from Google's Matt Cutts that helped me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzA_VBHtuCk.

I hope it helps others in the same situation as I was.